# DOMXpath: Extract string until Colon

Tags: xpath

I have a few examples here:

```
<p>
<font>Mortal Combat: A very good gamenbsp;</font>
</p>

<p>
<font>Call of Duty: Don't buy this game.</font>
</p>

<p>
<font>Street Fighter 2: Not the best game, but it's OK!</font>
</p>
```

This is so far I have come:

```
/p/font[text()="Mortal Combat" or text()="Street Fighter 2"]
```

I want to extract only if I match, but I don't wish to extract anything after the Colon `:`

In this sample the output I wish for is:

```
Mortal Kombat

Street Fighter
```

I have tried to do something with preceding-sibling, but it didn't work.

Comment: The whole text itself is a TextNode DOM node, so you'll have to extract the interest part in your programming language, not in XPath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`substring-before()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring-before) in XPath 1.0

Would that work for you?

```
//p/font[substring-before(., ":")="Mortal Combat" or substring-before(., ":")="Street Fighter 2"]/text()
```

This would not output the sub-string though, just matches text node that have one of these substrings.

Applying `substring-before()` again around the expression will only get you 1 result.

```
substring-before(//p/font[substring-before(., ":")="Mortal Combat" or substring-before(., ":")="Street Fighter 2"]/text(), ":")
--> "Mortal Combat"
```

You would have to loop on the matching text nodes, and apply `substring-before()` or a substring extraction using you programming language.